# Blender shaded mode view problem

Tags: 3d-view

I am very new to blender and might be asking a very silly question,

I am using blender 2.8 ..in shading workspace or in lookdev mode all the objects appear black..but when rendered it appears fine. See attached image for reference. Please help.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Shading_View_Problem.blend file that you uploaded is not showing the problem for me.

The only way I can reproduce what you have is if I enable the Scene World lighting in the Shading drop down menu then in the Shader Editor I switch from Object to World and then disconnect the Background node from the Worlds Output node. This **sometimes** results in what you are experiencing but not always. The 3D view remains with the Black cube etc until I move the cursor back to the 3d Editor again, then the scene seems to update and turn the whole view black.

[image]

I have no idea if this is a bug or something to do with the graphics card (mine is a 1080 ti with updated drivers) or something else completely.

All I can suggest is that you download 2.80 again, sorry.

Comment: Hi 3fingerdfrog, thanks a lot for your support...I too think that it may be due to graphics card..mine it too old...I would work on your suggestion to download a newer version of blender 2.8 also..thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try:

Top right of the **3D Editor** window, open the **Shading** drop down and make sure that you have the **Scene World** lighting option unchecked.

[image]

Edited, Below is Abhisek's updated screenshot showing his Shader drop down menu.

[image: View after update]

Comment: Hi 3fingeredfrog, Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to do as you mentioned but situation is still the same. screen shot is attached for reference.

Comment: What does your Shading editor Shader dropdown menu look like ? sharing your .blend file here  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  would be helpfull.

Comment: Hi 3fingeredfrog, thanks again. It's just the default startup file with basic cube and light and camera in blender 2.8...I would send the blend file in the mentioned link.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5870" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5870/)