# Lookdev mode is showing objects as only black and white

Tags: 3d-view

as the title says not sure why its happening.
I'm very new so sorry i can't add much more info.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
image of whats happening.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Which version of blender? Also had the issue shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131649/blender-shaded-mode-view-problem on locally built version  2.80 or 2.81 (can't remember)  Fixed by v2.82 (definitely for  2.83)  @DuarteFarrajotaRamos keep meaning to bookmark that one.  Hope all is well in P'gal.- _These are interesting times we live in_

Comment: 2.82a. Could redownloading 2.82 help?

Comment: Since the reflection probe doesn't render properly it's probably either an issue with your graphics driver or a bug in Blender.

Comment: just fixed it. saw a comment @DuarteFarrajotaRamos made about opening a new file and switching to eevee and then switching back to the original file. Thank you :)